# Weird sound problems cropped up on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Please help! Today I was trying to edit some home video with KDENLive and when I'd try to preview my videos, they'd play for about a second then lock up the program.

In troubleshooting, I discovered:

If I reboot the computer, most multimedia files play fine: MP3, MP4, FLV, AVI, WMV, etc. But as soon as I try playing an MPEG-2 file, the video freezes. (Using SMPlayer. With VLC it plays, but has no sound.) After that, I have no sound on any format, though they still play. However, trying to play videos on Facebook or YouTube, they lock up after a second or so as well. BUT: If I start an MP3 file and keep it playing, all the other videos work. However, when I shut them all down, they won't restart.

If I reboot the computer and go directly to Sound Settings | Test Sound, I get no sound. Then my video files also have no sound (MP3, MP4, etc.), just like when I try playing an MPEG-2.

Is there some commonality there? Like, does KDENLive, the Test Sound function, and the MPEG-2 files use FFMPEG or something? Because it seems like as soon as I execute any of those three things, I'm screwed.

Are there any diagnostics I can run? I'm kinda dead in the water on editing our home videos until I find out what happened!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with KDENLive, or Ubuntu .... so take the following with a grain of salt... that said, most non-linear editors will need to parse the MPEG-2 streams before rendering them properly.

You could try transcoding the media into another file format before bringing them into KDENLive.

If you want to maintain file quality, and don't have an issue with storage space, try using ffmpeg to create an uncompressed AVI:

`ffmpeg -i [YOUR FILE PATH] -c:v rawvideo -c:a pcm_s16le -f avi [YOUR OUTPUT PATH]`

If your MPEG-2 files are interlaced, try adding `-vf yadif=1` into the command above to deinterlace.

I know that doesn't quite address your issue, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Something about trying to start the MPEG-2 files kills my sound and corrupts something so that videos then won't play. Weird thing: if I reboot, fire up an MP3 in VLC and let it loop, everything works fine as long as it's playing. (I edited an entire 2 hour video on KDENLive doing that.) But as soon as I let the MP3 stop, the problem re-occurs. I've been writing software for 20+ years, so I know a bit about troubleshooting, but this has me baffled.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried playing the files in ffplay alone?  Does that have any issues?

Comment: ffplay does not appear to be on my system. Synaptic says it could install libavcode-extra-53, but must first remove libavcodec53 and libavutil51. I'm hesitant to start making changes without a clear plan.

Comment: Sorry, but I am utterly unfamiliar with Linux... I've been stuck in a Windows box for the last decade.  If those errors were coming from a Windows machine, I would guess that it was a codec conflict in your registry... I know that doesn't quite carry over to the Linux world though - so hopefully someone with experience there can chime in.